# Possible Workaround for Inaccurate Floating Point Rounding?

Tags: php

I have created a PHP system that is having some problems with rounding.  After looking further into this, I found that it goes back to the round function in PHP.

For instance...

> Rounding 2047.615 to 2 decimal places gives 2047.62 (as expected)
>
> Rounding 2048.615 to 2 decimal places gives 2048.61 (doesn't round up as expected)

I understand that the issue here most likely goes back to the inaccuracy of representing floating numbers in binary, but what is the most elegant way to take care of such issues?

Comment: If this is a problem for you, you should reexamine the assumptions behind your algorithm. Because then it seems that you're assuming that .615 can be represented exactly in a floating-point number, which is can't. This implies that you probably have more fundamental problems than rounding.

Comment: Hint: If you're working with currency, then note that 204861.5 _is_ exactly representable. Work in cents, even when in floating point.

Comment: @Henning: If you're working with money, you shouldn't be using floating point at all.

Comment: @Robert, I think that's too knee-jerk a reaction, assuming that one has a reason to calculate with fractional cents in the first place (and that these fractional cents don't come from a source that's inherently decimal). IEEE-754 doubles can represent integral amounts of cents exactly up to amounts about the size of the entire global economy, and will add and subtract these cent amounts exactly. The important thing is to have the binary point in the right place, not whether there's anything behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [rounds as expected](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KGB2th) for me. Have you tried explicitly setting the **mode** parameter to `round()`?

```
round( 2048.615, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); // however, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP is the default
```

EDIT: It looks like `round()` was changed in PHP 5.3.0:

> Changed round() to act more intuitively when rounding to a certain
>   precision and round very large and very small exponents correctly.
>   (Christian Seiler)[2](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0)

Comment: PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP must be in a later version of PHP (I'm using PHP 5.1.6)

Comment: Once I upgraded to a newer version of PHP the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your particular `round` function is performing [Banker's Rounding](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm) (or PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN).

If you want a different kind of rounding, use one of the other PHP rounding variants:

```
<?php
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // 10
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 9
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 10
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // 9

echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // 9
echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 8
echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 8
echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // 9
?>
```

Comment: No, that's not it. The problem is that 0.615 cannot be represented exactly, so there's no occasion to use the rounding mode at all. (In contrast, 0.5 _can_ be represented; thus for your examples you see a difference).

Comment: @Henning: That doesn't really explain the rounding behavior the OP is describing. See jldeev's answer, and here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/KGB2th

Comment: Looking at codepad.viper-7.com/KGB2th, it looks calculates correctly in PHP 5.3, but not in PHP 5.2

Answer (score 1):

2048.615 is actually 2048.6149999999998, so it will round down to 2048.61 no matter the rounding method used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best solution I've come up with.  In the following snippet I separate out the integer and decimal parts of the number and then do my rounding just on the decimal part (which gives me more bits available to work on the decimal accuracy).  Does anybody see any problems with this solution?

```
function my_round($number, $decimals) 
  return floor($number) + round(round($number - floor($number), $decimals + 4), $decimals);
}
```

The "+ 4" is somewhat arbitrary (about half of the trailing digits of detail), but is attempting to be accurate enough without being so accurate as to run into the .499999999 issue causing this whole thing.